# javascript - 2 ways of defining array

Tags: javascript

i have some array, and inside array i want to define another array. Are those 2 definitions equal? many thanks :)

```
args: [{
    key: "data",
    ajaxOptions: {
        url: '/rest/adrestresource/1.0/activedirectory/findgroups%20test@lab.local%20Bezhesla1%20localhost%20CN=Builtin,DC=lab,DC=local',
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "xml"
    }
}];

args: function () {
    return [{
        key: "data",
        ajaxOptions: {
            url: '/rest/adrestresource/1.0/activedirectory/findgroups%20test@lab.local%20Bezhesla1%20localhost%20CN=Builtin,DC=lab,DC=local',
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "xml"
        }
    }];
}
```

It is used for configuring [a gadget](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/GADGETS010/Creating+a+Gadget+JavaScript+Object), documentation says: 
Either an array of objects or a function that returns one. T
First approach is working correctly, but defining array by function returning it is not working :?

Comment: the first one shouldn't have a semicolon at the end

Comment: You want to use getters and setters: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects

Comment: The second one needs to be called as a function => args()

Comment: That's confusing documentation, if it accepts function then it means exactly what you are doing. And calling args: function(){return ['blah']}() is really not passing a function. it's passing a value that the function returns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first example you have a property that is an array. The second example, it is a method that returns an array, so call it like:

```
// example 1
var myArray = Something.args; // property

// example 2
var myArray = Something.args(); // method
```

Comment: It could be args: (function () {return[]})() to return an array

Comment: ty Edorka, that is exactly what i needed :)